# Downloading pandas on macOS terminal

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, terminal

I'm taking a data analysis class, and I am currently trying to download pandas on the macOS terminal but it's giving me a hard time. I have tried everything from downloading homebrew to deleting old files but still, nothing is helping hopefully someone can shed some light! Below is what I am getting when I first enter in terminal

```
Searching for pandas
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/31/29/ede692aa6547dfc1f07a4d69e8411b35225218bcfbe9787e78b67a35d103/pandas-1.0.5.tar.gz#sha256=69c5d920a0b2a9838e677f78f4dde506b95ea8e4d30da25859db6469ded84fa8
Best match: pandas 1.0.5
Processing pandas-1.0.5.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-ury_vz/pandas-1.0.5/setup.cfg
Running pandas-1.0.5/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-ury_vz/pandas-1.0.5/egg-dist-tmp-PL43Bg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 13, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==41.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2316, in main
    **kw
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 418, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 679, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 705, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 890, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1158, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1144, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
    raise
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 44, in _execfile
    code = compile(script, filename, 'exec')
  File "/tmp/easy_install-ury_vz/pandas-1.0.5/setup.py", line 42
    f"numpy >= {min_numpy_ver}",
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
arpanbhomia@Arpans-MBP ~ %
```

Comment: You are using python 2.7 but pandas 1.0.5 only officially supports "Python 3.6.1 and above, 3.7, and 3.8.". You'll either need to upgrade to a new python like 3.8 (advised as 2.7 is done) or install a much older version of pandas, maybe 0.24

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) and download the latest Python version for your computer. As you've installed Homebrew, you can also install it from the terminal as follows:

```
$ brew install python
```

After you've installed the latest Python version, try to download Pandas again:

```
$ pip3 install pandas
```

If you want a more complete installation, you can download Anaconda, as it installs numpy, pandas, python, and other components all together. You can read more about it [here](https://www.anaconda.com/).